# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ae45033a0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm trying to get my iOS project to launch with my current location enabled on google maps. However, I am getting the following error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ae45033a0'

I have already added `-ObjC` to other linker flags for debug and release and I still receive that error. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to show your code, but you have called `animateToCameraPosition` on an instance of UIView, not GMSMapView. Did you remember to set the custom class on your map view in your storyboard scene?

Comment: YES!!! That worked!!! Thank you so much!!!